# Intersection of two subspaces defined by span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered a problem where I have to find the intersection of two subspaces.They are each defined by a span of two vectors in $R^2$. i.e.$$V=\operatorname{span}((1, -1, 1, 0)^T(=v_1), (5, -2, 0, 1)^T(=v_2)) $$ $$W=\operatorname{span}((-1, 1, 0, 1)^T(=w_1), (0, 1, -1, 1)^T(=w_1))$$
I know that these will be $R^2$ objects(plane) through the origin in the $R^4$ coordinates. So, the intersection of them will be a line passing through the origin.(if it ever exists.) However, I'm thinking of a easy way to find the exact direction vector of the intersection subspace. I thought of a way where I set $$av_1+bv_2=cw_1+dw_2$$
and then solve the linear system $av_1+bv_2-cw_1-dw_2=0$, find a, b, c, d, and put it again to $av_1+bv_2$ and find the intersection. However this seems to be unnecessarily long, and involving lengthy calculations. It also seems to be hard to apply when the dimension of V, W goes higher. Any reproducible ideas, please?

Comment: You only have to find Nullspace of the matrix $[v_1^T, v_2^T, - w_1^T,-w_2^T]$ to get $(a, b,c, d) $. Indeed, it will be lengthy process if dimensions of the subspaces are high.

Comment: Unfortunate.....Thanks for the answer!

Comment: But fortunately, if you are lucky, you may have $v_1,v_2,-w_1,-w_2$ as linearly independent set of vectors 